# Autosar-C++14 A4-5-1 std::ios

Tags: c++, autosar

I am attempting to use std::fstream and I would like to pass several options into the mode parameter.  A4-5-1 states that enum shall not be operated upon by arithmetic operators.  But I can't conceive of how I achieve the following without the or operator or some mess of explicitly casting down to integers, performing the operations and then explicitly casting back to enum which feels like I will run afoul of another rule (value not in enum range, probably).

`const std::ios_base::openmode mode{std::ios::out | std::ios::in | std::ios::app | std::ios::binary};`

Comment: Well doesn't that suck. And they aren't even really being used as `enum`s. I can see why the rule's in place, but you're tight that there's no appealing way around this.

Comment: To my understanding those [flags](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) aren't necessarily enums

Comment: They don't have to be, but in GCC's default library they sure are.

Comment: @user4581301 Yeah, but [bitmaskType](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BitmaskType) have stronger requirements than a generic `enum`, that *should* cover Autosar concerns.

Comment: Yea, bitmaskType is mentioned by some of the material I was reading as the way this is supposed to work.  But I didn't notice my stdlib defining this enum as being a bitmaskType.

Comment: Should, but we're talking a rule-checker that's probably only looking as far as "`enum`. Nope!" and ignoring the operator overloads. Solution: The rule engine needs improvement. Maybe log a bug with AutoSAR?

Comment: It's always a possibility with the scanners to register a false flag.  But it is likely the fault lies with Autosar/Scanner/GCC.  I'll leave the question open in case someone does have a compliant trick.